# QtRuby painting crashing on Windows but not Linux

Tags: ruby, qt, qt4, qt4.8, qtruby

I'm new to QT and am having crashes on Windows 7 x64 when trying to create custom paint events.  I'm using Ruby 1.9.3p125 and qtbindings-4.8.3.0-x86-mingw32.  This crash does not show up when on my work machine, Redhat Linux using Ruby 1.9.2p180 and qtbindings-4.6.3.4

I originally ran into this problem when following the IconEditor example from "C++ Gui Programming with QT 4" (ported to Ruby) but have simplified the issue in the below example.

This example code creates a timer to draw a simple line in a sub-classed QWidget repeatedly.  On Windows, the paintEvent fires ~440 times before Ruby gives a segmentation violation.  Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'Qt'

class Painter < Qt::Widget
  slots :startTimer

  def initialize(parent=nil)
    super(parent)
    setAttribute Qt::WA_StaticContents
    setSizePolicy(Qt::SizePolicy::Minimum, Qt::SizePolicy::Minimum)

    @counter = 0
    @timer = Qt::Timer.new(self)
    connect(@timer, SIGNAL('timeout()'), self, SLOT(:startTimer))
    startTimer
  end

  def sizeHint
    Qt::Size.new(200,200)
  end

  def paintEvent(event)
    puts "DEBUG: paintEvent #{@counter += 1} #{event.inspect}"
    painter = Qt::Painter.new(self)
    painter.setPen(palette.foreground.color)
    painter.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200)
  end

  def startTimer
    @timer.start(5)
    update
  end

end


app = Qt::Application.new(ARGV)
painter = Painter.new
painter.show
app.exec
```

Here is the backtrace:

```
DEBUG: paintEvent 440 #<Qt::PaintEvent:0x3328938>
DEBUG: paintEvent 441 #<Qt::PaintEvent:0x3327de0>
DEBUG: paintEvent 442 #<Qt::PaintEvent:0x3327420>
DEBUG: paintEvent 443 #<Qt::PaintEvent:0x3326928>
./main.rb:27: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0008 p:---- s:0024 b:0024 l:000023 d:000023 CFUNC  :method_missing
c:0007 p:0107 s:0022 b:0022 l:000021 d:000021 METHOD ./main.rb:27
c:0006 p:---- s:0017 b:0017 l:000016 d:000016 FINISH
c:0005 p:---- s:0015 b:0015 l:000014 d:000014 CFUNC  :method_missing
c:0004 p:0013 s:0011 b:0011 l:000010 d:000010 METHOD C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469
c:0003 p:0098 s:0008 b:0008 l:001aec d:0023bc EVAL   ./main.rb:41
c:0002 p:---- s:0004 b:0004 l:000003 d:000003 FINISH
c:0001 p:0000 s:0002 b:0002 l:001aec d:001aec TOP

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
./main.rb:41:in `<main>'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `exec'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/Qt/qtruby4.rb:469:in `method_missing'
./main.rb:27:in `paintEvent'
./main.rb:27:in `method_missing'

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll(ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15) [0x77d5f8b1]
C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll(WaitForSingleObjectEx+0x43) [0x76c01194]
C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll(WaitForSingleObject+0x12) [0x76c01148]
C:\Ruby193\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_vm_bugreport+0xf9) [0x62e5c61d]
C:\Ruby193\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_name_err_mesg_new+0x17a) [0x62d3a6fa]
C:\Ruby193\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_bug+0x2f) [0x62d3b45b]
C:\Ruby193\bin\msvcrt-ruby191.dll(rb_check_safe_str+0x1a4) [0x62dee1a0]
 [0x004011e6]
C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll(GetProfileStringW+0x12aa3) [0x76c4003f]
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll(RtlKnownExceptionFilter+0xb7) [0x77db74df]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------

* Loaded script: ./main.rb

* Loaded features:

    0 enumerator.so
    1 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/encdb.so
    2 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/iso_8859_1.so
    3 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/trans/transdb.so
    4 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults.rb
    5 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/rbconfig.rb
    6 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/deprecate.rb
    7 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/exceptions.rb
    8 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
    9 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
   10 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb
   11 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/version.rb
   12 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/requirement.rb
   13 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/platform.rb
   14 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb
   15 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/path_support.rb
   16 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/Qt/qtruby4.rb
   17 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/1.9/qtruby4.so
   18 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/Qt4.rb
   19 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/qtbindings-4.8.3.0-x86-mingw32/lib/Qt.rb
   20 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/utf_16le.so
   21 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/trans/single_byte.so
   22 C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i386-mingw32/enc/trans/utf_16_32.so
```

**Edit::**
Nothing like answering your own question...

The paintEvent class needs to include a "painter.end" statement.  I can't find documentation of this but it is in the examples included with qtbindings and I just missed it.  No doubt this calls the QPainter object destructor to prevent memory leaks from crashing the program.

Here's the corrected code:

```
def paintEvent(event)
  puts "DEBUG: paintEvent #{@counter += 1} #{event.inspect}"
  painter = Qt::Painter.new(self)
  painter.setPen(palette.foreground.color)
  painter.drawLine(0, 0, 200, 200)
  painter.end
end
```

Comment: When you find an answer to your own question, don't post it as an edit, post it as an actual answer and mark it as the correct answer. This will make it easier for someone to notice that you actually found a solution if they have a similar issue.